# Mapping custom data types using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, npgsql

I am using EF 6th database first approach with PostgreSQL.

In Postgres I have several custom data types such as:

```
    CREATE TYPE common.weekdays_type AS ENUM
   ('mon',
    'tue',
    'wed',
    'thu',
    'fri',
    'sat',
    'sun');
ALTER TYPE common.weekdays_type
```

Unfortunately EF code generator can't table rows where this custom data type is used.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829011/how-to-provide-npgsql-with-a-custom-data-type-as-a-parameter/8839210#8839210) I found reply from 2012 saying that there's no support but intention to add this feature to npgsql. Is there any ways to solve this issue now?