# Npgsql error datatable

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to send a datatable with Npgsql, but I get the following error:

> The CLR type System.Data.DataTable isn't supported by Npgsql or your PostgreSQL. If you wish to map it to a PostgreSQL composite type you need to register it before usage, please refer to the documentation.

THIS IS THE CODE, AND P_DETALLE IS THE DATATABLE VARIABLE:

```
Sub ADMINISTRAR_ARTEFACTO(ByVal P As E_ARTEFACTO)
    Dim CONECTION As New NpgsqlConnection
    Try
        CONECTION.ConnectionString = "Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=123;Database=ALURHE_DB"
        Dim COMMAND As New NpgsqlCommand
        With COMMAND
            .Connection = CONECTION
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "SP_ADM_ARTEFACTO"

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_SERIE", P.P_SERIE)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_TIPO_ARTEFACTO", P.P_TIPO_ARTEFACTO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_MODELO", P.P_MODELO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_MARCA", P.P_MARCA)

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_DETALLE", P.P_DETALLE)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_USUARIO", P.P_USUARIO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_ID_ARTEFACTO", If(P.P_TIPO_OPERACION = "M", P.P_ID_ARTEFACTO, DBNull.Value))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_TIPO_OPERACION", P.P_TIPO_OPERACION)
        End With


        CONECTION.Open()
        COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CONECTION.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        If (CONECTION.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
            CONECTION.Close()
        End If

        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

this is the postgresql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_adm_artefacto(
v_serie character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
v_tipo_artefacto integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_modelo character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
v_marca integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_detalle type_detalle_ac DEFAULT NULL::type_detalle_ac,
v_usuario integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_id_artefacto integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_tipo_operacion character DEFAULT NULL::bpchar)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
ROWS 0
AS $BODY$

DECLARE 

    VL_ID_ARTEFACTO INTEGER;
    VL_ID_DETALLE_AC INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF V_TIPO_OPERACION = 'I' THEN

        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID_ARTEFACTO),0) INTO VL_ID_ARTEFACTO FROM ARTEFACTO;
        VL_ID_ARTEFACTO:=VL_ID_ARTEFACTO+1;

        INSERT INTO ARTEFACTO (ID_ARTEFACTO,SERIE,TIPO_ARTEFACTO,MODELO,MARCA,USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION)
        VALUES (VL_ID_ARTEFACTO,v_serie,v_tipo_artefacto,v_modelo,v_marca,V_USUARIO,NOW());

        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID_DETALLE_AC),0) INTO VL_ID_DETALLE_AC FROM DETALLE_AC;
        VL_ID_DETALLE_AC:=VL_ID_DETALLE_AC+1;

        INSERT INTO DETALLE_AC(ID_DETALLE_AC,ID_ARTEFACTO,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,
                               USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION)
        SELECT VL_ID_DETALLE_AC,VL_ID_ARTEFACTO,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW()
        FROM (SELECT V_DETALLE.*) AS V_DETALLE;
        --VALUES (VL_ID_DETALLE_AC,VL_ID_ARTEFACTO,V_DETALLE.ID_COMPONENTE,V_DETALLE.PRECIO,V_DETALLE.CANTIDAD,V_DETALLE.SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW());


    END IF;

END;


$BODY$;
```

this is the type:

```
CREATE TYPE public.type_detalle_ac AS
(
id_componente integer,
precio numeric(10,2),
cantidad integer,
sub_total numeric(10,2)
);
```

I AM MODIFIED ON THE PART OF V_DETALLE

```
.
.
.
.Parameters.Add("V_DETALLE", NpgsqlDbType.Array / NpgsqlDbType.Composite).Value = {1, "COMPONENTE A", 10, 3, 30}
.
.
```

BUT THE FOLLOWING ERROR COMES OUT

> This NpgsqlDbType isn't supported in Npgsql yet: -44739243

Comment: I think the error message is clear. what type expect the store procedure?

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: wait for a type that I created

Comment: Looks like they add this feature in 3.1.7  Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39331110/3470178

Comment: hi Juan Carlos, 
I use the Npgsql-3.2.7 version

Comment: Your SP spect `type_detalle_ac` you need convert the row in the datatable to that type and do a loop to insert each one record on the data table.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: did you check the link above?

Comment: Hello Juan Carlos, I have added to the question the modifications but I get error

Comment: Well there are some difference between your and that link. So i suggest you do dome testing. Try do `INSERT` command first. Then try to do it with a SP. Also in other answer they use an array parameters. After you do some testing I suggest you ask another question with the specific problem

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, Npgsql doesn't support writing a DataTable to the database, mainly since AFAIK PostgreSQL doesn't support accepting a table as a parameter to a function.

Make sure you understand exactly how your PostgreSQL function looks like - which parameters it accepts - and then turn to the task of invoking that function with Npgsql.

Comment: hello Shay Rojansky, I added the function and the type in the question ,,, what could I do to invoke the function?

Comment: @nasck as Shay said  DataTable isn't a supported type.

Comment: then how could a table be sent?

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make sense... Your function accepts a parameter `v_detalle` of type `type_detalle_ac`, which is a single "row". DataTable is a *table* of these rows, not a single row. In other words, your function *really doesn't* accept a row (nor is it supported in an easy way).